# C++: ensure in compile-time that function is only called on a specified thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-analysis, static-assert

I have a method which tinkers with a complex structure that's not thread-safe. Normally, this is not a problem, as essentially all calls to this method should be made from initialization phase, which is supposed to be running in a single thread (the same one that we've started `main()` with).

However, it looks like some malicious component inside my codebase is indeed calling this method from non-main thread. I obviously can add a mutex/lock guard into this method as a safeguard against potential calls, but, from my perspective, this is a workaround, not a solution I'm looking for.

Of course, I can also add a runtime assert, i.e. something like:

```cpp
static std::thread::id s_main_thread_id

int main(...) {
    s_main_thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    // ...
}

void vulnerable_function() {
    ASSERT(std::this_thread::get_id() == s_main_thread_id);
}
```

... but that's not a guarantee.

**Question:** is it possible somehow to assert in compile-time that a certain method should be only ran from a certain (i.e. main) thread? I'd like to find rogue calls in my codebase and prevent that from happening again.

I've looked through [assert-like contracts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/contract) in C++20, but if I'm on the right path and/or I can apply it.

Comment: I am afraid there's nothing you can do at compile time to prevent that. Threads (their id's) are only accessible at runtime.

Comment: Why not just grep for all the calls to this function?

Comment: Why not fire up the old debugger and just figure out where and why other threads are calling your function, then fix the code.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is build some assert macros. Use your thread library to get thread identifiers. Save the thread ID the first time your code builds that data structure. Then assert it matches the current thread ID every time you enter those functions.

The CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) library uses this.

By wrapping these macros up like asserts, the preprocessor will remove them in release builds that set -DNDEBUG.

If you ever had to get fancier, CEF also has functions to post and handle messages so that other threads can have work done on the UI thread by posting a message to it.

Answer (score 1):

> ...all calls to this method should be made from initialization phase...

Forget about threads.  If the function is only meant to be called during "initialization," then make sure that it can only be called during initialization:

```
boolean initialization_is_complete = false;

problematic_function(...) {
    ASSERT(! initialization_is_complete);
    ...
}

initialize_the_system(...) {
    ...
    call_things_that_call_problematic_function(...);
    ...
    initialization_is_complete = true;
}
```

---

> The ASSERT() will happen in run-time, right?... I want some static analysis tool to be able [prevent] that at compile-time.

I am not a C++ expert. The only compile-time ways that I know of to prevent the "unauthorized" use of any thing is to make its declaration `private` to a class or `static` in a compilation unit.* If I could make `problematic_function()` be `static` in a compilation unit whose public symbols are only useful at "init" time, then that's what I would do.

On the other hand, if my fellow developers had good reasons why they wanted to call `problematic_function()` at other times, from other places, then I would seriously consider re-designing it so that it would not be a problem.

---

* If you pull some `constexpr` trick or some `template` trick that I didn't think of (I am *not* a C++ expert), then I bet that it still will depend on a declaration of *something* that is in-scope for the init code, and out-of-scope for all the other code.

---

Going back to your original idea, which was to prevent any "wrong" threads from calling the function: There actually is no such thing as a thread in the C++ language. The `std::thread` data type is provided by a library, and the compiler itself has no way of knowing the identity of the thread(s) that will execute the code that it translates.

That is to say, `std::this_thread::get_id()` is not `constexpr`, and there is no *compile-time* way to compare it with the identity of any `std::thread` in the program.

Maybe some day they'll define `std::main_thread`...

Comment: This `ASSERT()` will happen in run-time, right? And I want some static analysis tool to be able that in compile-time. Ideally, I want the compiler with some sort of `constexpr` magic to be able to determine that.

Comment: @GreyCat, see what I added to my answer, above.